# Reference another Excel Worksheet via a Keyword

Tags: excel

I am not sure if this is too ambitious. Currently I'm generating a bunch of pivot tables through our server (I won't go into detail) but our main stocktaking spreadsheet references these generated pivot tables weekly and pulls their figures through.

i.e using code ='C:\Users\ITS1\Documents\Test\Establishment\190303[Stocktake.xlsx]Data4'!$D$3 which is simple enough - just referencing whatever figure is in that cell on the pivot table.

There is a particular bunch of figures on some pivot tables each week called 'Redemption' which, depending on what other kind of sales an establishment generates, shift to different cells each week. So I can't reference them like other figures which are always fixed to the same cells on every generated pivot table.

Is there a way I can reference the pivot table by the keyword 'Redemption' and take the figure from the cell directly next to it which is the actual figure we need to record?

While this isn't hugely urgent, it would be quite handy. These figures can just be manually entered but just trying out some automation to eliminate my human error :)

Comment: Does it shift which pivot table the "Redemption" field is in? Or does the first cell of the pivot table shift location on its worksheet? Or is it the location of the "Redemption" field within its pivot table which changes? Depending on what shifts could impact the solution(s) offered.

Comment: The location of the 'Redemption' field within the pivot table changes. It always remains on the same sheet within the workbook, but just shifts around the sheet by a few cells

Comment: The absolute reference to a cell will work with the external file being closed. If you need to engage formula logic to look up the correct cell, then the external workbook needs to be open. This may negate the benefit of using a formula over a manual transaction.

Comment: @teylyn Ideally the idea here is for me to not have to open the external workbook. So you are right, doesn't seem like i'd be getting any benefits from this.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to have to open the external workbook, this approach might be feasible:

In the external workbook, create a helper sheet that uses a formula to look up the Redemption field value. This could possibly be done with a GetPivotData formula. The exact formula depends on your data and without seeing that I can't write it.

The idea here is that the helper sheet and the location of the cell on the helper sheet does not change. When the pivot table is refreshed, the formula calculates the result.

In the other workbook you can now use an absolute reference to that helper sheet and cell and don't need to open the external file to retrieve the value.